# SED How to change lines to blank

Tags: sed, blank-line

I want to change the lines that include a keyword to blank

that s what I initially thought

```
sed -i "/.*$keyword.*/c\ " file;
```

But this actually replaces lines with a space
Thus when I search for the blank lines `"^$"` doesn't work

What can I do about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) : Stream EDitor

Using sed, you could **address** a line by its number **or** its content:

```
'/keyword/s/.*//'
```

Mean:

- On lines containing *keyword*, replace everything by nothing.

### `c\` command

I didn't already used `c\` syntax... For rightly answer to this question, I've tried this:

```
seq 1 5 |  sed '/3/c\'| hd
00000000  31 0a 32 0a 34 0a 35 0a                           |1.2.4.5.|
00000008
```

wich don't give expected result.

```
seq 1 5 |  sed '/3/c\ '| hd
00000000  31 0a 32 0a 20 0a 34 0a  35 0a                    |1.2. .4.5.|
0000000a
```

Reflect the meaning of this question,

```
seq 1 5 |  sed -e '/3/c\\n'| hd
00000000  31 0a 32 0a 0a 0a 34 0a  35 0a                    |1.2...4.5.|
0000000a
```

Don't give attended result, and finaly

```
seq 1 5 |  sed '/3/c\\'| hd
00000000  31 0a 32 0a 0a 34 0a 35  0a                       |1.2..4.5.|
0000000a
```

seem to be **the right answer** to this question: *You have to add a leading backslash to `c\` command in order to produce an empty line.*

```
sed -e '/keyword/c\\'
```

### Other [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) ways

#### Replace strings

My first idea was to *replace everything* by *emtpy string* by using

```
sed -e '/keyword/s/.*//'
```

#### Delete line

The question suggest to use `c\` command:

```
sed -e '/keyword/c\\'
```

#### Using empty *hold space*

@Kalanidhi suggest to use *hold* buffer, wich could work if they is empty, but by using `g` instead of `G` command,

> from `info sed`:
>
> `g' Replace the contents of the pattern space with the contents of the
>        hold space
>
> `G' Append a newline to the contents of the pattern space, and then
>        append the contents of the hold space to that of the pattern space.

So the command using this idea could be:

```
sed -e '/keyword/g'
```

#### Emptying the content of pattern space

But I think re-reading `info sed` pages, that the more appropriated command was suggested by @potong *(+1)*, by using `z` command

> from `info sed`:
>
> `z' This command empties the content of pattern space

```
sed -e '/keyword/z'
```

Comment: not exactly the same between `c\ `and `s/.*//` because `c` send the new line(s) directly to the output where `s///` empty the buffer that could be printed or manipulated. In this case, the result is the same due to simple output result without other manipulation except that loop is direct to next line after a `c` (performance interest)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu yes, this is why I suggest to use `'/keyword/c\\'` instead of `'/keyword/c\ '`

Comment: on my aix, `c\\` is not allowed (not posix i guess)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i "/$pattern/z" file
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the use of `z` in sed ?

Comment: @Kalanidhi for `z` and other goodies see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-Commands.html#Extended-Commands).

Comment: You could find *infos* about `c\ `, `g`, `z` and all other command locally by hitting: `info sed`.